# Gmail rendering issue for Emails

Tags: email, gmail, html-email

I am getting Emails notifications on my Gmail Id. Full Email is coming when i am viewing in my mobile devices whereas Email is getting truncated and half of the email is being viewed when i am viewing the same email on desktop.

Can any one please tell me the exact reason for this

Thanks for the help in advance.

I tried decreasing the size of the Email when sending from my side. Email size is also 80kb but still this does not helped in.

Comment: Email size pre-send can be different from email size after-send. Your ESP can add/change code. Check the code weight of an email after the send.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Gmail feature and has been around for sometime.

> On Gmail, emails larger than 102 KB will be clipped, so the recipient
> will have to click on the “[Message Clipped] View entire message” link
> to access the content. Between the text, the HTML code, the links, the
> URLs and the other elements, this size limit is quickly reached in the
> case of a newsletter for example.

[Source](https://captainverify.com/blog/prevent-gmail-truncating-email.html)

A way around it is to keep your email below the 102kb mark.